# Multiple interfaces to one class

Tags: c++, c++11, interface, c++14

I am trying to come up with an elegant solution for the problem of offering multiple interfaces to a class in C++.
Suppose we have the classes B,C and D. B and C need customized/controlled access to the class A whereas D can have direct access. The solution for offering such interfaces needs to be extendable. Future interfaces might be specialized for only one particular class.

Currently I am creating interface classes (IA_1, IA_2) which have a reference to the class A. B and C will be provided whith instances of those interfaces and can access A through IA_1 respectively IA_2 in a customized/controlled manner. The situation is depicted in the image below.

[image]

This has the advantage that I don't need to touch class A when implementing a new interface. New interfaces can utilize old interfaces through inheritance. Classes which need access to A will only be able to do through their particular interface.

The implementation in C++ would look like this:

```
class A{
public:
  void foo();
};

class IA_1{
public:
  void foo(const B& b);
private:
  std::weak_ptr<A> m_A;
};

class IA_2{
public:
  void foo();
private:
  std::weak_ptr<A> m_A;
};

class B{
  std::unique_ptr<IA_1> m_A;
};

class C{
  std::unique_ptr<IA_1> m_A;
};

class D{
  std::weak_ptr<A> m_A;
};
```

The interfaces get a weak_ptr to A because I don't want classes which are only accessing A to participate in its lifetime management.

Currently I am creating an interface object for every instance of B or C, although they are all doing the same. I already thought about creating only one interface object and give every instance of B and C a reference (shared_ptr) of the corresponding interface. In that way I will only have one object for every interface. Maybe this is already a case of premature optimization to reduce the memory footprint of the application.

Is there a way to further improve this design or take a totally different approach?

Comment: Your UML is confusing because the connecting lines are reversed ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#UML_notation))

Comment: Seems like premature pessimisation to me instead. Having N weak pointers to an object is better than having N shared pointers to a weak pointer to an object.

Comment: @stefaanv You are correct. I have corrected the UML diagram.

Comment: Yep, much clearer

Comment: You seem to be implying `A` is a singleton?  Or are you just saying there are many `B`s and `C`s per `A`?

Comment: @Yakk It's the latter case.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a complete answer, just my thoughts.

Cons:

- Extra interface classes introduced
- Extra indirection, with extra maintenance per supported call
- construction: extra factory needed for interface pointing to object
- weak pointers: solve the case where the pointer becomes dangling

Pros:

- clear control over interface to the class
- extra safety over lifetime (can be checked, but should also be handled)
- limited change needed on object (friends?)

About the 1 instance per interface: The footprint will be a bit lower, but you need extra management over accessing that 1 instance.